# Issue in def variable while performing sort in Karate Framework

Tags: karate

I have noticed that while passing a def as a list for simple sorting I am observing that apart from return values the original variable is also sorted.

```
* def original = ['a','b','c']

* def javaInstance = new (Java.type('package.subpackage.StringSort'))
* def sortedContent = javaInstance.m1(original,'desc');

* print sortedContent 
* print original
```

Both "sortedContent" & "original" def variables are sorted.

Below is the java fn:

```
public class StringSort {
  public List<String> m1(List<String> s, String order) {

    Collections.sort(s);

    if(order.equals("asc"))
        return s;
    else {
        Collections.reverse(s);
        return s;
    }       
}
}
```

Output:
sortedContent = ['c','b','a']
original = ['c','b','a']

I don't understand why original def variable is sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how [Java works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)). Create a [clone](https://github.com/intuit/karate#copy):

```
* def original = ['a','b','c']
* copy temp = original
```